# Programmatically change user permissions for table Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Is there any way of changing a user permissions for table in Access database using C#? I have a problem to read and insert into table which has denied read/insert rights for current user. When I change manually permissions works, but I want to change it programatically by C#. I've been tried this SQL command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE myTable TO Admin
```

but it's seems that I don't have rights for that action. This how it looks in Access.

[image: access screenshot]

Edit:

To call @rybo103 method, I've used this code, but I'm getting an error.

```
DAO.DBEngine engine = new DAO.DBEngine();
string path = @"C:\Database.mdb";
DAO.Database db = engine.OpenDatabase(path, false, false, "");
List<DAO.PermissionEnum> flags = new List<PermissionEnum>();
flags.Add(DAO.PermissionEnum.dbSecFullAccess);
AddPermissions(db, "ECR", "Admins", flags);
```

Error:

```
Cannot open the Microsoft Office Access database engine workgroup information file.
```

Comment: Does it work without `TABLE` like this? -> `GRANT SELECT ON myTable TO Admin`

Comment: @HansUp I've got an exception by run this command: `Cannot open the Microsoft Jet engine workgroup information file.`

Comment: Please tell us where you are stuck with that error.  Do you know what an Access workgroup information file is?  Do you know how to find yours?  Do you know how to reference it in your OleDb connection string?

Comment: This error I've got at `document.UserName = groupName;` line in @rybo103's code. I know just a basic of Access workgroup information file. Yes, I can find mine. I don't know nothing about this reference.

Comment: I think it should be simpler to execute the `GRANT` statement from an OleDb connection.  In the connection string, reference your workgroup information file with the `Jet OLEDB:System Database` property as explained at [Access connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: This works, when I added system db to connection string I haven't no longer problem with premission on table even without running `GRANT` command. But, I have a question. How to dinnamically locate and add system db?

Comment: I don't know how you'll do that.  You may need to ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HansUp sugestons helped. Finnaly, I added `Jet OLEDB:System Database` property to my OleDb connection string and it works. Even it works without `GRANT` command.

Answer (score 1):

In Access you will need to use DAO to make these sort of schema changes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835373.aspx

```
void AddPermissions(DAO.Database db, string tableName, string groupName, IList<DAO.PermissionEnum> addFlags)
{
    var container = db.DaoDB.Containers["Tables"];
    var document = container.Documents[tableName];
    document.UserName = groupName;

    int permissions = document.Permissions;
    foreach (var flag in addFlags)
    {
        permissions = permissions | (int)flag;
    }

    document.Permissions = permissions;
}
```

Comment: At first, thanks a lot for answer. I have problem to open my database, I got an error: Cannot open the Microsoft Office Access database engine workgroup information file. Can you help me with this?